# Button to update the text in a field

Tags: jquery

So I have some things working with an input field and a button that adds a new copy of the field. Next I want to update the initial input field with a new question on the click.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="input" id="input" size="30" value="What is your name?">
<a href="#" id="addScnt">Enter</a>

<div id="namess">
<div>
    <label for="names"></label>
</div>
</div>
```

JQUERY:

```
var $input = $("#input");

$(function () {
var scntDiv = $('#namess');
var i = $('#namess p').size() + 1;

$('#addScnt').live('click', function () {
    $('<p><label for="names"><input type="text" name="names_' + i + '" id="name" size="30" value="' + $input.val() + '"></label><a href="#" id="remScnt">  Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    return false;
});

$('#remScnt').live('click', function () {
    if (i > 1) {
        $(this).parents('p').remove();
        i--;
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/miketrujillo/nV2tA/

I'm afraid I'll have to come up with a whole new approach to get this to work.. json and array?

Comment: you will have duplicate id for appended element

Comment: where  have you tried to update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Change your new added inut id for remove duplicate id like you have set name for each input.
2) then add an event on click of newly created input element.

try like this:

```
 $('<p><label for="names"><input type="text" name="names_' + i + '" id="names_' + i + '"size="30" value="' + $input.val() + '"></label><a href="#" id="remScnt">  Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
```

and new element event :

```
$(document).on("click",'input[id^="names_"]',function(){

    $(this).val("what is your new question?");
    // do what ever you want here

})
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nV2tA/15/)

Comment: This comes close but the names field is updated. Trying to get it in the input field... I tried just switching to input where you have names but that doesn't work.

Comment: i did not understand what you are trying to do. can you explain it more?

Comment: where you see "What is your name?" That should update with the string in your example. What you have is almost perfect but its coming in on the added field not the initial field. if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 0):

Does this solve your problem? This should update your initial input field once you click the input button.

```
 $("#addScnt").click(function(){
     $(this).attr("value", "Ask your new question here...");
 }
```

Ok so you may want to do it like this below. This will do those things in one click.

```
$('#addScnt').live('click', function () {
    $('<p><label for="names"><input type="text" name="names_' + i + '" id="name" size="30" value="' + $input.val() + '"></label><a href="#" id="remScnt">  Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
    i++;
    $(this).attr("value", "Ask your new question here...");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: when I tried this I got a new question on a click right away. it should update when I click the button not the field...

I think I implemented it wrong though obviously...

Comment: @krp Whoops! Accidentally referenced the wrong ID. I just fixed it so that should update the field based on clicking the button.

Comment: heres a fiddle of another attempt...

http://jsfiddle.net/miketrujillo/nV2tA/

this works well except the generated field is getting the new string along with the first string.